# Host ASP.NET Core with multiple version dotnet runtime like Django's virtualenv?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a VM run CentOS 7.1 and Apache to serve ASP.NET Core 1.1 application.
I would like let individual web application use it own target runtime.
For example:

eShop Web-> dotnet core 1.0

Blog Web -> dotnet core 1.1

Testing Site -> 2.0.0 beta
...

I read some post and recommend use the docker, but my VM only have 8GB ram and limit CPU power, so I am look like is it something like Django virtual environment to target different version by each applications.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any special tooling to make this happen. .NET Core supports side-by-side installations.

The way dotnet selects the runtime to use by using the contents of (appname).runtimeconfig.json file. The SDK will generate this file when you build the app. If you compiled for "netcoreapp1.0", the build output will contain this file, and it should look something like this:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "1.0.4"
    }
  }
}
```

If you have installed dotnet to `/usr/share/dotnet/`, when you execute "dotnet app.dll" it will load the runtime from `/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.4/`

For more details in this file, see https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.1/Documentation/specs/runtime-configuration-file.md

Comment: I have running dotnet core 1.0.4 LTS version  on the server. Does it mean it cap to the veraion 1.0.4, so that I cannot deploy the apps version higher than that? thanks you.

Comment: It caps the version at 1.0.*. The runtime will roll-forward to newer patch versions, but not major or minor versions. i.e. If you install 1.0.5, it will roll-forward to 1.0.5. You can disable this with the "applyPatches" setting: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.1/Documentation/specs/runtime-configuration-file.md#sections